# Skipping header while Parquet file loading into Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

need to skip the header while loading parquet file into Snowflake, could someone help on this?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't think you can, you can only do that for structured data.

Answer (score 0):

For Parquet, file format options are:

```
 COMPRESSION = AUTO | SNAPPY | NONE
     BINARY_AS_TEXT = TRUE | FALSE
     TRIM_SPACE = TRUE | FALSE
     NULL_IF = ( '<string>' [ , '<string>' ... ] )
```

More details: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html#type-parquet

Also, you can review the loading Parquet tutorial at the below link:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/script-data-load-transform-parquet.html#script-loading-and-unloading-parquet-data